# Prove that every uncountable closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The continuum hypothesis states that there is no set $X$ such that $\aleph_0<|X|<2^{\aleph_0}$. In this problem we have to prove that the continuum hypothesis holds for closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. In order to prove that statement, we can show that there is an injective function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ into $A$, and then apply the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem. However, I have not been able to prove the existence of this function.

Comment: This is the Cantor--Bendixson theorem. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property

Comment: @EdwardH Thank you!

Comment: Your proof of the continuum hypothesis for the closed subset $A = \{0\} \subset \mathbb R$ does not work: there is no injective function $f : \mathbb R \to \{0\}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I said that the subset is uncountable in the title of the post

Comment: Okay, yes. In general it's helpful if the post and the title can be read independently.